# Using :not() in CSS to avoid certain class from using those properties

Tags: html, css

So I saw online that using the `:not()` selector in CSS makes it so that whatever class you specified in the parenthesis will not apply those properties too. But that doesn't seem to be the case for me. For example,

```css
.test .btn div:not(.classtoavoid){
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

So when I do what I showed above, it doesn't apply those properties to the `.btn` class where they don't have the div with class (`classtoavoid`). Am I using the `:not` selector incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

```
.test .btn div:not(.classtoavoid){
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

This does not select the `.btn` class, it selects any div which is a descendant of `.btn` which does not have the selected class.

You can't apply CSS to a parent based on a child (at least not yet).

You want [**`:has()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) but that basically has almost (actually none) no support as yet.